# How to reverse the javascript effect back to the display:none when button is clicked again?

Tags: javascript

```html
<button onclick="updateProfile()">Change profile pic</button>
<form method='POST' id='form2' style="display:none;">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">
            Join Today
        </legend>
        {{form2|crispy}}
    </fieldset>
</form>

   
function updateProfile() {
    console.log(this)
    document.getElementById("form1").style.display = "block";
}
```

I can only change the effect one way. How to change the effect back to display: none so that form isn't visible again?

Comment: add a boolean variable and check whenever you click the button what the value of the boolean is. toggle between display and not displayed depending on the value and then change the boolean's value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will do the trick:

```js
updateProfile = () => {
  let el = document.getElementById("form2");
  if (getComputedStyle(el).display === 'none') {
    el.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    el.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="updateProfile()">Change profile pic</button>
<form method='POST' id='form2' style="display:none;">
  <fieldset class="form-group">
    <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">
      Join Today
    </legend>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Or alternatively, you may take advantage of the `data` attributes:

```js
updateProfile = () => {
  let el = document.getElementById("form2");
  el.setAttribute('data-state',
    el.getAttribute('data-state') === 'open' ? 'closed' : 'open');

}
```

```css
form[data-state=open] {
  visibility: visible;
}

form[data-state=closed] {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="updateProfile()">Change profile pic</button>
<form method='POST' id='form2' data-state="closed">
  <fieldset class="form-group">
    <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">
      Join Today
    </legend>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Or even some plain old classes:

```js
updateProfile = () => {
  let el = document.getElementById("form2");
  if (new Set(el.classList).has('show')) {
    el.classList.remove('show');
    el.classList.add('hide');
  } else {
    el.classList.remove('hide');
    el.classList.add('show');
  }
}
```

```css
.show {
  display: block;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="updateProfile()">Change profile pic</button>
<form method='POST' id='form2' class="show">
  <fieldset class="form-group">
    <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">
      Join Today
    </legend>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Hope that helps,

Comment: Don't rely on `Element.style.property` as a getter to tell you what style is applied on an element. `getComputedStyle` is your friend.

Comment: @Kaiido Interesting, I've updated my first block to respect that. I'm going to have to look more into `getComputedStyle`. If you can save me some time, what's the reason behind it?

Comment: Because `Element.style` only reflects the `style` attribute content, but you can very well have external style-sheets dictating what's the real value should be. https://jsfiddle.net/ja2n89Lx/ But as a rule of thumb, you want to deal the less possible with Element.style anyway. For instance to do what OP wants to do, they would be better to toggle a class on the container and to react on this class from CSS. It's easier to control a full layout this way.

Answer (score 3):

To achieve expected result, use below toggle option with boolean variable

1. Set variable to false by default
2. On every click of function , toggle its value
3. Based on condition of variable, set **block** or **none**

```js
var toggle = false
function updateProfile() {
  toggle =!toggle
    document.getElementById("form2").style.display = toggle ? "block" : "none";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="updateProfile()">Change profile pic</button>
<form method='POST' id='form2' style="display:none;">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">
            Join Today
        </legend>
        {{form2|crispy}}
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add condition to check `document.getElementById("form2").style.display == "none"`

```js
function updateProfile() {
    //console.log(this)
    if(document.getElementById("form2").style.display == "none") {
    document.getElementById("form2").style.display = "block";
    }else{
    document.getElementById("form2").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="updateProfile()">Change profile pic</button>
<form method='POST' id='form2' style="display:none;">
<input type="text" />
</form>
```

Comment: Don't rely on `Element.style.property` as a getter to tell you what style is applied on an element. `getComputedStyle` is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

#### Form hide/display:

This method uses `class` for hide/display of the form. You can simply add style to your `.css` file.

```
    <button onclick="updateProfile({d:this});return false;">Change profile pic</button>
    <form method='POST' id='form2' class="di-0">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">
                Join Today
            </legend>
            {{form2|crispy}}
        </fieldset>
    </form>


    <script>
        function updateProfile(z){
            var x,a;
            x=/(di-0)/i;
            if(x.test(z.d.nextElementSibling.attributes.getNamedItem('class').nodeValue)){a=1}else{a=0}
            switch (a){
                case 1:
                    z.d.nextElementSibling.attributes.getNamedItem('class').nodeValue='di-2';
                    break;
                case 0:
                    z.d.nextElementSibling.attributes.getNamedItem('class').nodeValue='di-0';
                    break;
                }
        }
    </script>
    <style>.di-0{display:none!important}.di-1{display:inline-block}</style>
```

#### Form display/hide:

If you wish to do otherwise, you can change `class="di-0"` to `class="di-1"`:

```
    <button onclick="updateProfile({d:this});return false;">Change profile pic</button>
    <form method='POST' id='form2' class="di-1">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">
                Join Today
            </legend>
            {{form2|crispy}}
        </fieldset>
    </form>


    <script>
        function updateProfile(z){
            var x,a;
            x=/(di-0)/i;
            if(x.test(z.d.nextElementSibling.attributes.getNamedItem('class').nodeValue)){a=1}else{a=0}
            switch (a){
                case 1:
                    z.d.nextElementSibling.attributes.getNamedItem('class').nodeValue='di-2';
                    break;
                case 0:
                    z.d.nextElementSibling.attributes.getNamedItem('class').nodeValue='di-0';
                    break;
                }
        }
    </script>

    <style>.di-0{display:none!important}.di-1{display:inline-block}</style>
```

This method would also work in other forms. The key is to have the `hide/display` tag right after the `button` or action tag, such as an `a` tag.

```
    <a href="#" onclick="updateProfile({d:this});return false;">Change profile pic</a>
    <div class="di-0">
        Display | Display | Display
    </div>


    <script>
        function updateProfile(z){
            var x,a;
            x=/(di-0)/i;
            if(x.test(z.d.nextElementSibling.attributes.getNamedItem('class').nodeValue)){a=1}else{a=0}
            switch (a){
                case 1:
                    z.d.nextElementSibling.attributes.getNamedItem('class').nodeValue='di-2';
                    break;
                case 0:
                    z.d.nextElementSibling.attributes.getNamedItem('class').nodeValue='di-0';
                    break;
                }
        }
    </script>

    <style>.di-0{display:none!important}.di-1{display:inline-block}</style>
```